# W8 Store App Gridview Binding

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013

I'm new to using MVVM and I'm having some problems that I think may just require me to flatten data, but I hate to do that if there is a better way.  I have the GroupedItemsPage that VS 2013 sticks into the project and I have bound my list to it, and my group names show up fine, but I haven't figured out how to do the items in the group.  I have bound my GridView to List and each group has a List in it that contains all the items for that group.

```
    <CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="groupedItemsViewSource"
        Source="{Binding Groups}"
        IsSourceGrouped="true"
        ItemsPath="Items"
        d:Source="{Binding Groups}"/>

    <GridView
        x:Name="itemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Padding="116,137,40,46"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
        SelectionMode="None"
        IsSwipeEnabled="false"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="250" Height="250">
                    <Border Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageID}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Height="60" Margin="15,0,15,0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" Foreground="{ThemeResource ListViewItemOverlaySecondaryForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="15,0,15,10"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsWrapGrid GroupPadding="0,0,70,0"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <GridView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,2">
                            <Button Foreground="{ThemeResource ApplicationHeaderForegroundThemeBrush}"
                                AutomationProperties.Name="Group Title"
                                Style="{StaticResource TextBlockButtonStyle}" >
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="0,-11,10,10" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{StaticResource ChevronGlyph}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Margin="0,-11,0,10" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </GridView.GroupStyle>
    </GridView>

public class Group
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<Item> Items {get;set;}
}

public class Item
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public Guid ImageID {get;set;}
}
```

I spend a couple hours searching last night without luck, though that may be not knowing what I need to find.  The default code from MS has a ton of stuff in it, so I tried to thin it down to what I think are the relevant parts.

Comment: Can you share the GridView ItemTemplate

Comment: Just updated and put the entire gridview in the post.  I know what I have for the bindings isn't right, I just don't know what I need to do to get the correct binding without flattening the object model.  I feel like there needs to be another binding option in the GridView Group to specify where it gets the individual items from, but I didn't see anything to do that.